# Make HTML Link to Play Audio (without HTML5 player)

Tags: html, audio

I want to have users be able to click a link to play audio on my website, but I don't want there to be an actual 'player', per se, on the page.  Is there a way to make a link play an audio file?  I **do not** want to go to an actual file.  I simply want to play that audio in the "background" of the current page.

I have tried this:

```
<audio>
   <source src="My Audio.wav" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
```

However, that doesn't even show anything at all.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<audio id="player" src="My Audio.wav"></audio>

<div>
    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">Play</a>
</div>
```

By doing that, the `href="#"` will link to that exact same page, and when clicked, the `onclick` event will play the audio.

Just a note, it is not a bad idea to have a couple of different file formats.  That will assist in cross-browser compatibilities.